# Is there a way to see the questions that have truly zero answers not just those with no accepted answers?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I am interested in answering what I can but it seems like the "unanswered" are mostly answered but not accepted. Some have dozens of responses. I think the author has just not come back. 
It also seems like there is a disincentive to accept an answer since upvoting stops then.

I want to go after unanswered that are new (that is; no responses).  I have looked through the site but can't see a way to do this.

Comment: If you go to Questions > Unanswered you can then pick the "No answers" tab to get the questions without any answers. It's definitely a confusing naming scheme though. The questions under "Newest" will most likely also be unanswered.

Answer (score 4):

If you go to Stackoverflow [Search Page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=), you will find a few filters you can enable while searching.

Simply use `answers:0` with your search query.

All unanswered(0 answers) url:https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0